# Writing C code in Lisp

Tags: c, lisp, root

Recently I have had to write code in C as the platform I am using for a project I am undertaking- namely root- uses a C/C++ command line interpreter (CINT). However, I want to remain coding in Lisp. In 'ANSI Common Lisp' Graham states that one can write code using a combination of C & Lisp. Naggum however, goes a step further- he states that it is possible to write C code using Lisp.

How does one do this?

Comment: maybe he means it in a way similar to "it's possible to write assembly in C".

Comment: What implementation of Lisp are you using (this is crucial for the answer, because different implementations may use diffferent FFI interfacees)?
What does " C++ script and command line interpreter" mean? Interpreter of C++ as a scripting language?

Comment: I'm using Common Lisp- sorry those were meant to be separate statements- I'll remove the first to focus on the task at hand.

Comment: Naggum meant generating C code from Lisp. Since C is quite a flexible low-level language, it is a perfect target for many DSLs. And Lisp is suited well for implementing DSL compilers. See, for example, C code generation facilities in Wolfram Mathematica.